# python real time plot using funcanimation giving blank graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, real-time, pyserial

I am trying to plot a realtime graph using matplotlib's FuncAnimation class. The data is coming from arduino using pyserial library. I have tried the following code to plot in real time but the graph is empty, I can see the axes, ticks etc but not the plot. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import serial
import os
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd


fig = plt.figure()  

port= 'COM10'
baudrate = 9600
timeout = 2

ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)

def animate(i):
    j = 0  
    while True:
        try:
            loadcells = ser.readline()
            loadcells = loadcells.decode('utf-8').rstrip().replace('\t','').split(',')
            print(loadcells)
            loadcell1 = float(loadcells[0])
            # loadcell2 = loadcells[1]
            plt.cla()
            plt.plot(loadcell1)
            plt.pause(0.001)
            j+=1
            # plt.plot(loadcell2)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e1:
            print(e1)
            ser.close()

        

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,    
                    frames = 200,  
                    interval = 0.1,  
                    blit = False) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have an infinite loop in `animate()`. `FuncAnimation` works by calling `animate()` repeatedly at a pre-defined interval (`interval=0.1`).

You need to rewrite your `animate()` function where you read the serial port, plot the result, and return (no `pause()` either).

Comment: Ok will try this and update you. Thank you